# How to run a project with command line arguments (switches) after building in Monodevelop?

Tags: c#, monodevelop

How to run a project with command line arguments (switches) after building in Monodevelop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Project -> Options -> General -> Custom Commands like here

[image: Mondevelop run with command line argument]

Comment: I have the «Project Options» grayed out o.o

Answer (score 3):

Run the project using the "Run -> Run With -> Custom Parameters" menu option, or set the arguments in the project options (Run section).

Comment: ⁺¹, that is. Sad that the monodevelop have no this option per project.

Comment: It was too early to be happy. Alas, this option doesn't affect debug at all.